Error Propagation of $10^{x\pm\delta x}$
I have a error in the following form:
$$y = 10^{x\pm \delta x}$$
where $\delta x \ll x$. Given this, I need to sum two $y$ values; $y_1 + y_2$. Then what will be error propagation...?
I have tried to use the Taylor series approximation. Hence:
$$\delta y \approx \frac{dy}{dx} \delta x$$
since $y=10^x$, we obtain;
$$\delta y = 10^x\ln(10)\delta x$$
Thus:
$$y_1 + y_2 = [10^{x_1} + 10^{x_2}] \pm [10^{x_1}\ln(10)\delta {x_1} + 10^{x_2}\ln(10)\delta {x_2}]$$
But this feels somewhat wrong...any ideas?

Why does it feel wrong?  Note that $10^{x\pm \delta x}=10^x 10^{\pm \delta x}$ so the factor $10^x$ is correct.  If your error is in an exponent it better be really small.

@RossMillikan I can say that $\delta x/x \approx 0.01$ so I guess thats small enough...?

I am not sure...its mostly about the last equation...

The fact that $\delta x$ is in the exponent turns an absolute error in $\delta x$ into a relative error in $y$.  $\delta x/x \approx 0.01$ will lead to an enormous error in $y$ is $x$ is reasonably large.  Try it for $x=3,$ for example, then for $x=10$.

@RossMillikan Hmm actually my $x$ is around 10 and $\delta x$ is around 0.02. Can I for instance some over log values...llke $$log(y_1) + log(y_2) =(x_1 + x_2) \pm \sqrt{\delta x_1^2 + \delta x_2^2}$$

No.  The sum of logs is not the log of the sum.  If $\delta x$ is about $0.02$ then $y$ is good to a factor about $1.6$, so for $x=10$ it is from $0.6\cdot 10^{10} \text{ to }1.6 \cdot 10^{10}$  If that is useful accuracy you must be an astronomer.
